# I can no longer test run my app on iOS devices

Tags: ios, xcode

I've been working on my app for a while and recently I haven't been able to run the app on iOS devices. I keep getting an error saying "App installation failed: Could not inspect the application package"

I looked up this error and tried doing what others did to resolve it, but nothing worked for me. A lot of answers said that there couldn't be non latin characters in the title, that doesn't effect me. I tried 'cleaning' the project multiple times. I deleted the derived data but that didn't help either. How do I fix this issue so I can continue to test on iOS devices.

I don't know what data share here to help resolve the issue.... soooo if you need anything just ask.

I've already tried **XCode > Preferences > Accounts**, removing all apple ids and re-logging in.

Comment: I'm having the same problem, and I'm not sure how to fix it either... :/